# How can I get my result logged horizontally rather than vertically?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

Hello you beautiful coders!
Today I've been working on a little quiz called "Chessboard" but ran into a weird situation.
but my code is spitting out  results vertically but I need to make it horizontally so that I can repeat this process a few more times to make a board out of it. Here's my code:

```js
let value = 8;

for (i = 1; i <= value ; i++) {
  if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
    let x = i;
    console.log(x);
  } else {
    let y = " ";
    console.log(y);
  }
}
```

this above code outputs

```
2

4

6

8
```

How can I make these results show horizontally like so:

```
2  4  6  8
```

So that I can repeat this process in a new line afterward?
I've been thinking about this for awhile but.... I might just be too dumb to figure this out?

I THINK I have to nest this if function again in this function to achieve this but not sure how...
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: each console.log outputs into a new line. you can assign your one line values to a variable then finally log to console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an empty string at the beginning of the code, append the results to it, and log it to console, as illustrated below:

```
var res = "";

let value = 8;

for (i = 1; i <= value ; i++) {

  if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
    let x = i;
        res += x + ' ';
    } else {
        let y = " ";
        res += y;
    }
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

A console.log will always show on a new line in the console. I would add each result to an array and then convert the array into a string. Then console log it once.

```js
let value = 8;

// create empty array
const results = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
  if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
    let x = i;
    // rather than console logging, add to empty array
    results.push(x);
  } else {
    let y = " ";
    results.push(y);
  }
}

// convert array to string, seperated by spaces
const str = results.join(" ");
console.log(str)
```